# Barcode Reader for existing Mobile Application

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, html, mobile

I have a mobile application that I developed using angular, html5, java and oracle to handle upload and download of my company related work orders. Now I need to implement the barcode reader functionality to the same application and save the details to the DB. Is there a way that I can do this in angular or jsqrcode?

Any advise would be helpful, as I completely new to mobile development.

Comment: Though u don't have to use their tools, u might be interested in seeing how the Cordova barcode scanner plugin is being used here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/WASFAQs/entry/using_a_barcode_scanner_with_worklight?lang=en

Comment: Thank you nemesisfix. But Cordova is ide for Phonegap kind of native app.  Since our application is browser based I am not sure if we can use it. Are you aware of any jsqrcode that does not need flash ?